# C++ SSO : How to programatically find if a std::wstring is allocated with Short String Optimization?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, wstring

How to programatically find if a `std::wstring` is allocated with `Short String Optimization`? I was trying to detect such cases and use `reserve` to move out of the SSO.

The below code prints a small difference in the addresses:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main () 
{
    std::wstring str = L"H";
    std::cout<<&str<<" "<<(void*)str.data()<<"\n";
}
```

Output example:

```
0x7ffc39465220 0x7ffc39465230
```

[image]

Although in windows console app the address comes exactly same:

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about determining if the wstring uses SSO, but the problem to which you believe the solution requires a wstring that is not SSO-ized?

Comment: You can't rely on `std::wstring::data` to point to the start of the string object even without SSO.  `struct string { size_t len; size_t capacity; charT* data; ...};` would be a valid non-sso string that would give you a difference of addresses.

Comment: @NathanOliver you could check that it pointed in the range `&str`, `&str + 1`

Comment: Why +1 as hardcoded?

Comment: @SayantanGhosh: Because `&str` is a typed pointer. In C++ `+1` increments a pointer by one object, not one byte.

Comment: Thanks. An reason in a simple windows console app both the addresses are exactly same?

Comment: Seems odd, but you can always read the code and/or hexdump the memory region `[&str, &str + 1)` to figure it out for yourself. And please don't post pictures of text, it offends my delicate sensibilities.

Comment: Looks like it was due to debug vs release build in VS. In debug the addresses are not exactly same but in release build they are.

Answer (score 6):

There are two main ways to go about it:

1. Just straight-up test it.

   Remember to use [`std::less`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) to get a full order, and [`std::addressof`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to account for overloaded `op&` in weird classes.

   ```
   template <class T>
   constexpr bool uses_sbo(T&& t) noexcept {
       auto less = std::less<const volatile void*>();
       auto p = std::addressof(t);
       return less(t.data(), p + 1) && !less(p, t.data()));
   }
   ```
2. Compare the capacity.

   This relies on the implementation being *sensible*, meaning never allocating dynamically when the current capacity suffices, and not dynamically allocating an initial buffer on principle.

   ```
   template <class T>
   constexpr bool is_minimal(T&& t) noexcept {
       return t.capacity() == T().capacity();
   }
   ```

Both were generalized for all contiguous containers.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
bool ssoTest1(const std::basic_string<T>& s)
{
    return s.capacity() == std::basic_string<T>{}.capacity();
}

template<typename T>
bool ssoTest2(const std::basic_string<T>& s)
{
    uintptr_t r = s.data() - reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&s);
    return r <= sizeof(s);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v3b57Y

Comment: That subtraction is UB, AFAICT. Also, I'm not sure why you didn't generalize fully.